# Creating 1:1 relationship in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, relationship-class

I'm trying to build out a connected relationship between two tables. The requirements include the following:

> A row shall be entered into the `B` table for every record in the `A` dataset. A 1:1 relationship shall be established between the two tables based on "guid_id" field.

The "guid_id" field is in both tables and is of the type `GUID`.

I have added a 1:1 relationship class using the `arcpy.CreateRelationshipClass_management` function.

However, when I insert a new row into table `A`, table `B` does not update.

How do I do this in ArcPy?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong as I've never tried to do what you are asking, so may be another might correct me? You give zero information about how you have created your relationship class, but I know if you create a *composite* relationship then if you delete a row in table A then the related row in table B is deleted.  But I don't think it works when you create a row in table A, to cause an insert in table B and then update the ID field with the ID in table A, which is what you are asking about.

That said latest version of ArcPro has [Attribute rules](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/an-overview-of-attribute-rules.htm) that trigger on inserts. Some sample code is [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/attribute-rule-script-expression.htm#anchor4) that works across tables.  This might be the solution to automate the insert and update of the related table?

Here is a similar question on the [esri forum](https://community.esri.com/t5/developers-questions/arcade-expression-to-insert-a-record-into-a/m-p/1331051). Worth keeping an eye on it?